# Subscription on observable not reaching to oncompleted

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, system.reactive

I am trying to create an observable wrapper for wcf call and I created as bellow.

The method is like this,

```
private IObservable<List<string>> Search(string searchTerm)
    {
        return Observable.Create<List<string>>(o =>
        {
            var searchClient = new SearchServiceClient();
            var s = Observable
                .FromEventPattern<SearchCompletedEventArgs>(searchClient, "SearchCompleted");
            var subscription = s.Subscribe(
                r =>
                {
                    if (r.EventArgs.Error == null)
                        o.OnNext(r.EventArgs.Result);
                    else
                    {
                        o.OnError(r.EventArgs.Error);
                    }
                },
                    e =>
                    {
                        o.OnError(e);
                    },
                        () =>
                        {
                            o.OnCompleted();
                        });
            searchClient.SearchAsync(searchTerm);
            return subscription;
        });
    }
```

and method call is,

```
Search("reactive").Subscribe(
                   r =>
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("Result");
                   },
                   e =>
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                   },
                   () =>
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("Completed");
                   });
```

But it is never reaching to completed block. Could you suggest where I am going wrong?

@Edited on 26th

Thanks Petar Vučetin, Rarous and Lee Campbell. I have tested all three suggestions and all are working. But I like fallow the Petar's approach makes to single line of code. Even though it seems Observable.FromAsyncPatterns is depricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach if you can generate Async methods for your WCF client.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var searcher = Search("test").Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static  IObservable<string[]> Search(string searchTerm)
        {
            var searchClient = new Service1Client();

            return Task<string[]>.Factory.FromAsync(searchClient.BeginGetData, searchClient.EndGetData, searchTerm, null).ToObservable();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

@Rarous is correct. An event has no concept of completion so the FromEventPattern will never complete (or error). I think the favored approach is to use the Task.FromAsync.ToObservable as Petar Vučetin specifies, then consider the FromAsyncPattern that Rarous specifies. If you really want to, you could correct your code by making it look like this.

```
private IObservable<List<string>> Search(string searchTerm)
{
    return Observable.Create<List<string>>(o =>
    {
        var searchClient = new SearchServiceClient();
        var s = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<SearchCompletedEventArgs>(searchClient, "SearchCompleted");
        var subscription = s.Subscribe(
            r =>
            {
                if (r.EventArgs.Error == null)
                {
                    o.OnNext(r.EventArgs.Result);
                    o.OnCompleted();
                }
                else
                {
                    o.OnError(r.EventArgs.Error);
                }
            });
        searchClient.SearchAsync(searchTerm);
        return subscription;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Observables created from events never run to completion. As Petar mentioned, you can create Observables from Async pattern. Instead of casting `Task` to Observable, you can use factory method:

```
IObservable<string[]> Search(string searchTerm)
{
    var searchClient = new Service1Client();
    return Observable.FromAsyncPatterns(searchClient.BeginGetData, searchClient.EndGetData)(searchTerm);
}
```

Comment: I think the latest bits make FromAsyncPatterns obsolete.

Comment: I see, I'm still targeting .net 4.0.